# read answer not working on ssh bash -s script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell, grep

I have some commands to prompt for yes or no answer in my script, but the read answer command (interactive mode) not working, while running the script using `ssh bash -s script`.

```
ssh user@hostname bash -s < "/home/xxxx/devstop.sh"
```

it is not prompting the question from remote shell and exits to the source shell.

My script :

```
if [ "$count" -eq "0" ]
then
        echo -e "${GREEN}Tomcat Server stopped successfully on '$HOSTNAME' ${NC}"
elif [ $count -gt "0" ]
then 
        echo -e "${RED}Tomcat Server not stopped on '$HOSTNAME' please check it ${NC}"
        echo "Do you want to continue all the tomcat server shutdown process in -`date` "
echo "          Please Read the Above and Enter (Y/N) to Proceed or Stop to cancel shutdown processes :  \c"
read answer

value=`echo ${answer} | tr -s '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`

if [ "$value" = "Y" ]
then
        echo "                             Remaining tomcat Services are going down."
else
        echo "                             Cancelled tomcat Services shutdown process in '$HOSTNAME."
        exit 1;
fi

fi

ps -ef|grep tomcat|grep -v grep |grep -i "catalina.startup.Bootstrap start"

exit
```

Comment: Please [format the code in your post properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow/51145)  by indenting by 4 spaces. As it stands by now, it is nearly unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

The `read` works. But differently from what you think.

```
ssh user@hostname bash -s < "/home/xxxx/devstop.sh"
```

This tells `ssh user@hostname bash -s` to get its stdin from the file `devstop.sh`. So when it comes up to your

```
read answer
```

It will take the next line from stdin as input for the `read`. In your script, this is an empty line. Because of the empty line, your answer will be empty.

You can test this locally:

```
$ cat <<EOF >it
read a
echo $a
echo $a
EOF
$ bash it
q
q
q
$ bash < it
echo $a
```

The first `q` is the keyboard input.